# Python triple string quote declaration

Tags: python, string

I use the triple string in the following way:

```
str="""jeff"""
str=""""jeff"""
str=""""jeff""""   # error
str=""""jeff """"
```

The third one is error, could anyone explain why this is error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three quotes terminate a string, so this

```
str=""""jeff""""
```

is parsed as this:

```
str= """ ("jeff) """ (")
```

The trailing quote is the problem.

BTW, looking at the [BNF definition](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)

```
longstring      ::=  "'''" longstringitem* "'''"
                     | '"""' longstringitem* '"""'
```

it's obvious that the star `*` is non-greedy, I don't know though if this is documented somewhere.

In response to the comment, this

```
 str = ''''''''jeff'''
```

is interpreted as

```
(''')(''')('')(jeff)(''') <-- error, two quotes
```

and this

```
 str = '''''''''jeff'''
```

is interpreted as

```
 str = (''')(''')(''')(jeff)(''') <-- no error, empty string + jeff
```

Comment: what happens in this case `str = ''''''''jeff'''`, it has only 3 trailing quotes and still an error

Answer (score 1):

Only use 3 quotes.

The second string is interpreted as: "jeff

The third string is interpreted as: "jeff, followed by a stray quote.

Answer (score 0):

str="""jeff""" --> str 'jeff'

str=""""jeff""" -- > multiline str 'jeff'

str=""""jeff""""   # error --> here parser thinks that you declaring "", "", jeff, "", ""

str=""""jeff """"  # error --> same as previous one

```
>>> """"a""""
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    """"a""""
            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> """"a """"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    """"a """"
             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

To avoid it do like this """\"a \""""

Also, as *[tng345](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9290108/657384)* mentioned, you can look in BNF