# what does these characters (''') mean in python language?

Tags: python, syntax

I have this code in python

```
''' if a:
    b = c
'''
```

is ''' suggesting that this code is just a comment or this will actually execute?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Also, did you read the Python tutorial?  For example, http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth thanks. I looked it up on google but nothing helpful came up.

Comment: Googling "python triple quote" worked just fine for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In some cases, when you need to include really long strings (e.g.
>   containing several paragraphs of informational text), it is annoying
>   that you have to terminate each line with \n\, especially if you would
>   like to reformat the text occasionally with a powerful text editor
>   like Emacs. For such situations, ``triple-quoted'' strings can be
>   used, e.g.

Documentation (http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node70.html)

Triple quotes are also used for docstrings ([Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings)),

```
def my_function():
...     """Do nothing, but document it.
...
...     No, really, it doesn't do anything.
...     """
...     pass
...
>>> print my_function.__doc__
Do nothing, but document it.

    No, really, it doesn't do anything.
```

Also take a look at these questions:

- [Python triple string quote declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290058/python-triple-string-quote-declaration)
- [How does Python's triple-quote string work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520548/how-does-pythons-triple-quote-string-work)

Answer (score 1):

It is just a string literal. It uses triple-quoted style so, citing the [Python reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> In triple-quoted strings, unescaped newlines and quotes are allowed
>   (and are retained), except that three unescaped quotes in a row
>   terminate the string. (A “quote” is the character used to open the
>   string, i.e. either ' or ".)

In your case, it seems it is not part of a variable assignment. So it is probably a [documentation string or docstring](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-docstring).

It is similar to a comment because is used to document code. It is not executed but evaluated and recognized by the compiler available through `__doc__` attribute of class, function or module.